# Automatically page between silverlight controls

Tags: silverlight

I have a set of Silverlight controls and I want to create a webpage that will automatically alternate  between these controls. Any idea how I go about doing this?

The order that they are displayed and the period of time each one is displayed for needs to be configurable, but any tips on just getting the basic paging to work would be great.

The controls are currently hosted in a asp.net WinForms, so I could auto page the WinForms, or I could have a master Silverlight control that hosts the other controls and dictates the paging. In either approach I'm unsure of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a single Silverlight 2 application and do all the paging inside the control.

You can see an example of how to switch between Silverlight controls on my old blog post over [here](http://craign.net/2008/03/11/how-to-switch-silverlight-usercontrols/).